# TextWatcher StringBuilder append method appends CharSequence to both StringBuilder objects

Tags: java, android, append, stringbuilder

I'm trying to replace the displayed value of the EditText view with characters, while at the same time keeping the original input in another StringBuilder object.

Here's the code:

```
final StringBuilder stringBuilderHiddenPassword = new StringBuilder();
    final StringBuilder mPass = new StringBuilder();
    pass = new StringBuilder();
    etPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            stringBuilderHiddenPassword.append("*");
            etPassword.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            etPassword.setText(stringBuilderHiddenPassword);
            etPassword.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            pass.append(s);
            Toast.makeText(Pass.this, pass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

First inputed character displays in the Toast as the original character inputed, but the 2nd one adds a `*` to it. So if I input `a` it displays `a`, if I input `aa`, it displays `aa*`, for `aaa` it's `aa*a**` and so on.

How do I separate these objects from being both appended at the same time? The code should append to only `stringBuilderHiddenPassword`, but it's clear that's not how this method works.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by using the `replace` method on the original string:

```
replace = pass.toString().replace("*", "");
Toast.makeText(Pass.this, replace, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: no, this is not what you should do, you should use a custom `TransformationMethod` instead, the docs say: *"TextView uses TransformationMethods to do things like replacing the characters of passwords with dots, or keeping the newline characters from causing line breaks in single-line text fields."*